# $modal.open caches OLD copy of UI

Tags: angularjs, modal-dialog, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am opening a modal dialog with the following:

```
    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
        animation: false,
        templateUrl: '../templates/ResponseModal.html',
        controller: 'ModalResponseCtrl',
        size: 'lg',
        resolve: {
            response: function () {
                return selResponse;
            },
            cmt: function () {
                return cmt;
            }
        }
    });
```

Everything operates correctly.  However, if I change the `ResponseModal.html` on the server, the browser never re-reads the file.  The browser console shows no attempt to read it, or even check if it has changed.  Somehow, the old copy of the `ResponseModal.html` file is being cached in memory, and I can't figure out how to clear it out and force it to read again.  I use "shift-refresh" normally to force the browser to re-fetch all the parts -- but that does not work for this.  Closing the browser completely, and restarting it does not clear the cache.  Deleting all history works, but that is drastic.

Is there an **easier way** to convince the $modal mechanism to forget the old cached copy, and re-read the new one from the server?

Comment: Make sure that your browser settings are set to disable cache for development

Comment: I have not found that setting for Mozilla.  I saw a big discussion about Chrome and it only works when the developer panel is open -- which is better than nothing.  Do you know if this exists for Mozilla?

Comment: Not sure...I use Chrome primarily.  Its a pain to remember to have dev tools open, but you get used to it.

Answer (score 0):

jbrown's comment is absolutely right (and it's even easier in Chrome, just open up the inspector and it disables cache automatically while open), however there are times where you don't want those .html files cached at ALL since they could potentially change (or be generated) in a production environment.

Assuming you're using Apache, I've found in this use case that using .htaccess works great to disable the cache on certain view files. Let's be honest, in today's day it's not serving up .html files that are causing server load, it's the dynamic data driven stuff. Here's a simple way to disable (almost all) caching on your simple .html partials, using .htaccess

```
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 1 minute"
```

That stops it from floods, but also ensures it'll ask for a fresh version of the page in a reasonable timeframe. It's inherently flawed simply because there's a time factor involved, but this has worked well in my experience with similar use cases.

Answer (score 0):

Anytime you see/use `templateUrl` in Angular, think `$templateCache`.  Once the HTML template is downloaded the first time, it is stored in the `$templateCache` service and will not be updated again via normal application interaction.

Depending on your `Expires` and `Cache-Control` headers, a forced reload may not work.  Your best bet is to disable caching by the browser when the browser's debug window is open as indicated above.

Understand though that you should still dev test your application as a normal user would use your application and NOT rely on the refreshed caches.

Comment: I have same issue and my tags are set to no-cache, no-store.